# Saving a RichText document to the temp folder in a Windows Store App

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to save the content of a RichEditBox to my apps temporary folder, but I can't get it to work.

Here's the working code to save the file to disk, through the Save File picker:

```
// [code for savePicker. Not relevant because that all works fine]
StorageFile file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
editor.Document.SaveToStream(TextGetOptions.FormatRtf, stream);
```

Here's the working code to save a txt file to the temp storage

```
StorageFolder temp = ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;
StorageFile file = await temp.CreateFileAsync("temp.txt", 
                         CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, "some text");
```

So when I combined these to save RTF content to the temp folder, this is what I wrote:

```
StorageFolder temp = ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;
StorageFile file = await temp.CreateFileAsync("temp.rtf", 
                         CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
editor.Document.SaveToStream(TextGetOptions.FormatRtf, stream);
```

This doesn't work. I get an Access Denied error `(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))` on the second line `StorageFile file = etc`. However this same line of code executes fine in the second block above. It seems that when I follow it with file.OpenAsync it throws an error. Can someone point me in the right direction here? Is it something to do with `await`?

EDIT: I've accepted and upvoted the answer by Damir Arh, as it is the correct fix to this issue. My workaround solved the issue for me, but Damir Arh's answer addresses the root cause of the issue which is always better of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This block of code should work just fine; I even tested it, just to be sure:

```
StorageFolder temp = ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;
StorageFile file = await temp.CreateFileAsync("temp.rtf", 
                         CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
editor.Document.SaveToStream(TextGetOptions.FormatRtf, stream);
```

You have incorrectly identified, why it was failing. `CreateFileAsync` can't fail because it is followed by `OpenAsync`; the latter didn't even start executing when it failed.

The most probable reason was that you already had it open from a `Stream` that you didn't close properly. This can still happen even with the code that you have posted in the answer.

I would suggest you use `CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName` instead of `CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting`. This way a file with a different name will be created if for some reason it can't be with the original file name.

Also make sure you're properly closing the stream once you're done with writing. Since `IRandomAccessStream` implements `IDisposable`, you should always call `Dispose` on it when you don't need it any more. Or even better: put it in a `using` block which will do this for you.

Here's the code with these two changes applied:

```
StorageFolder temp = ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;
StorageFile file = await temp.CreateFileAsync("temp.rtf",
                            CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    Editor.Document.SaveToStream(TextGetOptions.FormatRtf, stream);
    await stream.FlushAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I figured it out based on this: This was part of an autosave function set to fire every 90 seconds. Since I didn't want to wait 90 seconds every time I wanted to test it, I set it to start 1 second after the app launch which also of course meant it fired EVERY 1 second!

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a workaround:

```
StorageFolder temp = ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;
StorageFile file = await temp.CreateFileAsync("temp.rtf", 
                         CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
string rtfcontent = "";
editor.Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.FormatRtf, out rtfcontent);
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, rtfcontent);
```

Comment: sometimes I can sit on a problem for hours, and then a minute or two after posting to StackOverflow I'll figure it out myself. Then it looks like I just didn't bother putting any time into it before posting! =( I'm never sure if I should delete these or leave them up, but who knows - they might benefit someone